# Looping lm models of column in a list of dataframes and outputting dataframes showing the slope and p values

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, lapply, lm

I want to loop `lm()` models for variable `i` (response) with an explanatory variable in a list of dataframes that are split by factor. Lastly, I want to create two dataframes that will show the `lm` coefficients: the first will show the `slope`  and the second the `p.value` with response variables tested in the models as cols and factor levels in rows.

I managed to run and print the output of the `summary` of the `lm` models, but not sure how to create the appropriate `slope` and `p.value` dataframes.

Here is what I've done:

```
data (iris)
iris_split = split (iris,f=iris$Species) ### Split the data by factor "Species"
```

I want to run lm models for each of the following variables
(treated as responses for the sake of the question)
with `Petal.Width`

```
vars = as.vector (unique (colnames (subset (iris, select = -c(Species, Petal.Width )))))
```

```
#Output:
#> vars
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length"
```

```
iris_lm = for (i in vars) { # loop across vars
  lm_summary = lapply (iris_split, FUN = function(x) 
                summary(lm (x[,i] ~ x[,"Petal.Width"]))) #Where (x) is levels of factors "Species"
                print(i) # so I could see which variable is tested in the model
                print(lm_summary)
}
```

How do I create the `slop.df` and `p.val.df`?
They need to look like this:

```
#> slop.df
#     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
#1     setosa       slope?      slope?       slope?
#2 versicolor       slope?      slope?       slope?
#3  virginica       slope?      slope?       slope?
```

The actual slopes need to be shown instead of the `"slope?"` placeholder, and the same goes for `p.val.df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

packages from the [tidyverse][1] make this fairly convenient:

```
iris %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(Species, Petal.Width),
                 names_to = 'variable',
                 values_to = 'value'
                 ) %>% 
    group_by(Species, variable) %>% 
    ## mind to return the model results as a list!
    summarise(model_summary = list(summary(lm(Petal.Width ~ value)))) %>% 
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(slope = model_summary$coefficients[2, 'Estimate'],
           ## p = model_summary$coefficients[2, 'Pr(>|t|)']
           ) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = Species,
                names_from = 'variable',
                values_from = 'slope')
```

Comment: Something does not work well with this code. I think the problem is evident at the `pivot_wider` function: `Error in stop_subscript(): ! Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column variable doesn't exist. Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @opel: maybe you need to load the iris data (`data(iris)`) again? What's the output of `rlang::last_error()` ?

Comment: Loading `data (iris)` doesn't help. Here is the `rlang::last_error()` output: rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_subscript_oob>
Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `variable` doesn't exist.
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ...
  3. tidyr:::pivot_wider.data.frame(...)
  4. tidyr::build_wider_spec(...)
  5. tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(names_from), data)
  6. tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
 14. tidyselect:::vars_select_eval(...)
 15. tidyselect:::as_indices_sel_impl(...)
 16. tidyselect:::as_indices_impl(x, vars, strict = strict)

Comment: 17. tidyselect:::chr_as_locations(x, vars)
 18. vctrs::vec_as_location(x, n = length(vars), names = vars)
 19. vctrs `<fn>`()
 20. vctrs:::stop_subscript_oob(...)
 21. vctrs:::stop_subscript(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

Comment: @opel: I'm at a loss there. The column 'variable' is created during `pivot_longer(...)` - or so it should (and is in my R session). Could you check whether the `pivot_longer` part results in a dataframe with a column called thus? `iris %>% pivot_longer(-c(Species, Petal.Width), names_to = 'variable', values_to = 'value')`

Comment: weird! now it worked. I'm not sure what it was yesterday that caused the problem. But restarting my r session and reloading the packages did the trick. Thanks!